# abnormal behaviour in cout. It is printing twice character array after declaration of another same valued character array

Tags: c++

So I was writing the code to print a character array in c++. The normal code is:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char X[5] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
    cout << X << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and it's printing:-`ABCDE` as expected but I tried to create another character array like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char X[5] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
    char Y[5] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
    cout << X << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and I thought that I'll get same output but it didn't happend.
the output was `ABCDEABCDE` I didn't understood why it happened.
At that time I was coding in my computer. So, I visited online c++ compiler and still got the same result.
Please anyone help me to understood why it happened?
I am using C++14 in my computer.
This is the link of [online compiler website](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/) on which I rechecked my code.

Comment: As already posted in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70804452/12416453) the behaviour is UB. The program's [output](https://godbolt.org/z/vPYh7zq6s) without adding `-O2` flag it gives `"ABCDE"`(can't count on it) but when compiled with `-O2` flag the output is `ABCDEP����`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behaviour is undefined.

`std::ostream`'s overload for a `const char*` (selected due to pointer decay), doesn't stop outputting until NUL is reached.

So including NUL terminators in both arrays is the fix:

```
char X[/*let the compiler do the counting*/] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 0};
```

&c.